# best way to read string into a table in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a string like this

```
some_string=  "something, something2, something3, something4, etc.."
```

i would like to read this string into a table like this:

```
field1 = "something"
field2 = "something2"
etc
```

what is the best way to do this in vba/sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable in an INSERT query, listing the field names to match up with their location in the string:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2, ... )
VALUES ( $some_string );
```

Comment: i need it split by the comma delimitter

Comment: What do you mean? In the example I gave, I assumed that $some_string is of the form "something, something2, something3, ..." as you gave in your example. It would expand to 

INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2, ... )
VALUES ( something, something2, ... );

Comment: If they are string values, this will break, as the VALUES list needs to have quotes around each for it to work. You could certainly do a some_string = Chr(34) & Replace(some_string, ", ", Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34)) & Chr(34) before concatenating it with the rest of your SQL, though.